# Slide out a View from screen

Tags: android, android-animation

I have the following animation xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <translate
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromYDelta="0%"
android:toYDelta="300%"
android:duration="2000"
android:zAdjustment="bottom" />
```

but when I call this on an onCLick(), the View slides down until its out, and then it just reappear in its default location. How to make it stay outside until I call another animation?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set [`View.GONE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#GONE) to the view you are translating via [`View.setVisibility()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29) when the `Animation` has finished, which can be detected by an [`AnimationListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html).

Comment: It also possible to call `setVisibility(View.GONE)` just before  `startAnimation()` call. Probably, if animation is needed often, use View.INVISIBLE instead of View.GONE to spead up animation and eliminate blinking is some corner cases (like full screen animation on old devices).

Comment: Yep, that is perfectly fine too. I myself have used both "ways" to achieve this, but nowadays my answer is mostly what I'll end up with. Personal preferences it is.